# Alexander the Great quotation: "I am indebted to my father for living, but to my teacher for living well."

Tags: traduction, anglais, histoire, grec

The other day I had a conversation with some colleagues about the role of teachers in the proper education of a student. I wanted to quote Alexander the Great:

> I am indebted to my father for living, but to my teacher for living well.

(Greek text: Εις μεν τον πατέρα μου οφείλω το ζην, εις δε τον διδάσκαλό μου το ευ ζην. Eis men ton patera mou ofeilw to zin, eis de ton didaskalo mou to ev zin)

Living well conveys here the "human qualities, personality, autonomy" triptych and not necessarily the material confort.
Here is my turn:

> Je dois à mon père ma vie, mais à mon précepteur la vie heureuse.

I was not understood and I had to explain the meaning of this quotation. Isn't the word 'précepteur' known nowadays? Does la 'vie heureuse' convey the meaning of living well?

Comment: I have to admit I had to look up *précepteur*. I think it's really rare nowadays (mostly because the position itself is rare)

Comment: "Isn't the word précepteur known nowadays?"  - Not really

Comment: Je crois qu'il faut ajouter que le fait que ce précepteur soit Aristote est peu connu. Alexandre met dans la balance deux hommes dont les valeurs, quoique vécues dans des domaines différents, sont d'égale importance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Une traduction plus naturelle (hors contraintes académiques) ou plus poétique :

> Je dois la vie à mon père, l’art de vivre à mon maitre.

Answer (score 7):

I found a more suitable translation: [La traduction raisonnée by Jean Delisle, Marco A. Fiola](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ap1jAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA226&lpg=PA226&dq=I%20am%20indebted%20to%20my%20father%20for%20living,%20but%20to%20my%20teacher%20for%20living%20well%20french&source=bl&ots=hCqKyhNpNq&sig=ACfU3U1SweGuTgjCvrvJ_7G661AZDLe3kw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiauYuUgb_nAhWnz4UKHbkYCXoQ6AEwDXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=I%20am%20indebted%20to%20my%20father%20for%20living%2C%20but%20to%20my%20teacher%20for%20living%20well%20french&f=false):

> Je dois à mon père de m'avoir donné la vie, mais à mon précepteur de m'avoir appris à vivre.

But I guess précepteur is not colloquial word nowadays.

Comment: Attention : percepteur et précepteur ne sont pas les mêmes mots !

Comment: @StéphaneVeyret Sans surprise, on voit assez peu de gens faire l'éloge de leur percepteur!