# "la notion de bonheur" vs "la notion du bonheur"

Tags: articles, différence

Quelle est la différence entre ces deux expressions?

> la notion **de** bonheur
>
> la notion **du** bonheur

Answer (score 2):

Ma vision, en tant que locuteur natif :

- "La notion *du bonheur*" est une contraction obligatoire de "La notion *de le bonheur*"

Vous devez donc opposer ces deux expressions :
"La notion *de bonheur*" vs. "La notion *de le bonheur*".
Cette dernière expression met l'emphase sur un bonheur en particulier. Sans contexte, cette opposition compare implicitement le *vrai* Bonheur (notez la majuscule) d'un bonheur *abstrait*, *désincarné*, *général*.

Comment: Il n'y a pas plus véritable que la subjectivité du ressenti. Votre remarque est néanmoins lourde de sens si on en maîtrise la subtilité. Est-ce vraiment l'endroit d'être sybillin ?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Non locuteur natif. Voici mon humble avis. (Merci @Reyedy et @yagmoth555 pour leur feedback).

**Le terme "notion du (de+le)/de la" fait référence à quelque chose de spécifique, tandis que "notion de" fait référence à un concept plus général.**

> Exemple : Rappelons la **notion de** contrainte. Nous allons nous souvenir de la notion (générale) de contrainte. Qu'est-ce que c'est ? Quelles sont, par exemple, les différences entre contrainte et force ? Quelle est sa dimension ? Etc.

Cf.

> Exemple : Rappelons la **notion de la** contrainte de Cauchy.

Ici on parle de quelque chose plus spécifique. Il existe plusieurs types de contrainte. L'accent est mis sur la contrainte selon Cauchy.

Autre exemple :

> **la notion de** force est difficile versus **la notion de la** force de cisaillement agissant tangentiellement sur la surface

**Pour le cas en question :**

> Exemple : **La notion de bonheur** est difficile à définir. C'est subjectif.

*Ici on parle généralement de cette notion. Cf.*

> Exemple : I am indebted to my father for living, but to my teacher for living well. *Je dois à mon père de m'avoir donné la vie, mais à mon précepteur de m'avoir appris l'art de vivre*. (Text grec : Εις μεν τον πατέρα μου οφείλω το ζην, εις δε τον διδάσκαλό μου το ευ ζην. Eis men ton patera mou ofeilw to zin, eis de ton didaskalo mou to ev zin).
>
> La **notion du** bonheur d’Alexandre le Grand n'a rien à faire avec le bonheur matériel auquel l'on pense de nos jours.

**Ici, on parle de quelque chose plus concret. À cette phrase l'accent est mis sur le bonheur selon Alexandre le Grand.**

Nota bene A :

> Le bonheur d'Alexandre le Grand. Tu parles de quoi ? Je parle du (contraction=de+le ; génitif) bonheur d'Alexandre le Grand.

Nota bene B :
Pour la citation d'Alexandre le Grand voir ici : [Alexander the Great quotation: "I am indebted to my father for living, but to my teacher for living well."](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41174/alexander-the-great-quotation-i-am-indebted-to-my-father-for-living-but-to-my)

Comment: Désolé, je ne comprends pas ce qui votre répense ait à voir avec ma question.

Comment: Non, pas vraiment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoir une notion sur quelque chose.
2. Avoir notion de quelque chose.

Les deux expressions sont quasi indistinctes pour plusieurs raisons.

Comment: Ça ne répond pas vraiment à la question, qui porte sur la différence entre "de bonheur" (indéfini) et "du bonheur" (défini) dans ce contexte.